# Combine several similar SELECT-expressions into a single expression

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

How to combine several similar SELECT-expressions into a single expression?

```
   private static Expression<Func<Agency, AgencyDTO>> CombineSelectors(params Expression<Func<Agency, AgencyDTO>>[] selectors)
    {

        // ???

        return null;
    }

    private void Query()
    {
        Expression<Func<Agency, AgencyDTO>> selector1 = x => new AgencyDTO { Name = x.Name };
        Expression<Func<Agency, AgencyDTO>> selector2 = x => new AgencyDTO { Phone = x.PhoneNumber };
        Expression<Func<Agency, AgencyDTO>> selector3 = x => new AgencyDTO { Location = x.Locality.Name };
        Expression<Func<Agency, AgencyDTO>> selector4 = x => new AgencyDTO { EmployeeCount = x.Employees.Count() };

        using (RealtyContext context = Session.CreateContext())
        {
            IQueryable<AgencyDTO> agencies = context.Agencies.Select(CombineSelectors(selector3, selector4));

            foreach (AgencyDTO agencyDTO in agencies)
            {
                // do something..;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show the data in the list. This is necessary in order to avoid loading unnecessary fields from the database.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not simple; you need to rewrite all the expressions - well, strictly speaking you can recycle most of one of them, but the problem is that you have different `x` in each (even though it looks the same), hence you need to use a visitor to replace all the parameters with the *final* `x`. Fortunately this isn't too bad in 4.0:

```
static void Main() {
    Expression<Func<Agency, AgencyDTO>> selector1 = x => new AgencyDTO { Name = x.Name };
    Expression<Func<Agency, AgencyDTO>> selector2 = x => new AgencyDTO { Phone = x.PhoneNumber };
    Expression<Func<Agency, AgencyDTO>> selector3 = x => new AgencyDTO { Location = x.Locality.Name };
    Expression<Func<Agency, AgencyDTO>> selector4 = x => new AgencyDTO { EmployeeCount = x.Employees.Count() };

    // combine the assignments from the 4 selectors
    var convert = Combine(selector1, selector2, selector3, selector4);

    // sample data
    var orig = new Agency
    {
        Name = "a",
        PhoneNumber = "b",
        Locality = new Location { Name = "c" },
        Employees = new List<Employee> { new Employee(), new Employee() }
    };

    // check it
    var dto = new[] { orig }.AsQueryable().Select(convert).Single();
    Console.WriteLine(dto.Name); // a
    Console.WriteLine(dto.Phone); // b
    Console.WriteLine(dto.Location); // c
    Console.WriteLine(dto.EmployeeCount); // 2
}
static Expression<Func<TSource, TDestination>> Combine<TSource, TDestination>(
    params Expression<Func<TSource, TDestination>>[] selectors)
{
    var zeroth = ((MemberInitExpression)selectors[0].Body);
    var param = selectors[0].Parameters[0];
    List<MemberBinding> bindings = new List<MemberBinding>(zeroth.Bindings.OfType<MemberAssignment>());
    for (int i = 1; i < selectors.Length; i++)
    {
        var memberInit = (MemberInitExpression)selectors[i].Body;
        var replace = new ParameterReplaceVisitor(selectors[i].Parameters[0], param);
        foreach (var binding in memberInit.Bindings.OfType<MemberAssignment>())
        {
            bindings.Add(Expression.Bind(binding.Member,
                replace.VisitAndConvert(binding.Expression, "Combine")));
        }
    }

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TDestination>>(
        Expression.MemberInit(zeroth.NewExpression, bindings), param);
}
class ParameterReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression from, to;
    public ParameterReplaceVisitor(ParameterExpression from, ParameterExpression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

This uses the constructor from the first expression found, so you *might* want to sanity-check that all of the others use trivial constructors in their respective `NewExpression`s. I've left that for the reader, though.

Edit: In the comments, @Slaks notes that more LINQ could make this shorter. He is of course right - a bit dense for easy reading, though:

```
static Expression<Func<TSource, TDestination>> Combine<TSource, TDestination>(
    params Expression<Func<TSource, TDestination>>[] selectors)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x");
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TDestination>>(
        Expression.MemberInit(
            Expression.New(typeof(TDestination).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)),
            from selector in selectors
            let replace = new ParameterReplaceVisitor(
                  selector.Parameters[0], param)
            from binding in ((MemberInitExpression)selector.Body).Bindings
                  .OfType<MemberAssignment>()
            select Expression.Bind(binding.Member,
                  replace.VisitAndConvert(binding.Expression, "Combine")))
        , param);        
}
```

Comment: +1 for writing all that code.  It could be made much simpler by replacing the nested loop with LINQ calls and a new `Parameter`

Comment: @Slaks maybe, maybe. It was already complex enough though - the reader probably has more chance to grok it in a more procedural layout

Comment: @Slaks - adding, just for fun

Comment: I had adapted you code and works fine..

But I would do like to work with expressions like Expression<Func<Agency, object>> selector1 = x => new { Name = x.Name }; instead of Expression<Func<Agency, AgencyDTO>> selector1 = x => new AgencyDTO { Name = x.Name };

How can I get it working with such anonymous types?

This expression (MemberInitExpression)selector.Body breaks if anonymous types is used

Answer (score 1):

If all of the selectors will *only* initialize `AgencyDTO` objects (like your example), you can cast the expressions to `NewExpression` instances, then call `Expression.New` with the `Members` of the expressions.

You'll also need an `ExpressionVisitor` to replace the `ParameterExpression`s from the original expressions with a single `ParameterExpression` for the expression you're creating.

Comment: Actually it is `MemberInitExpression` (the `NewExpression` is just the ctor); it can be done though (added)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this with a similar use case as mine (my selects targeted different classes based on the level of detail needed):

Simplified scenario:

```cs
public class BlogSummaryViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static Expression<Func<Data.Blog, BlogSummaryViewModel>> Map()
    {
        return (i => new BlogSummaryViewModel
        {
            Name = i.Name
        });
    }
}

public class BlogViewModel : BlogSummaryViewModel
{
    public int PostCount { get; set; }

    public static Expression<Func<Data.Blog, BlogViewModel>> Map()
    {
        return (i => new BlogViewModel
        {
            Name = i.Name,
            PostCount = i.Posts.Count()
        });
    }
}
```

I adapted the solution provided by @Marc Gravell like so:

```cs
public static class ExpressionMapExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<TSource, TTargetB>> Concat<TSource, TTargetA, TTargetB>(
        this Expression<Func<TSource, TTargetA>> mapA, Expression<Func<TSource, TTargetB>> mapB)
        where TTargetB : TTargetA
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "i");

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TTargetB>>(
            Expression.MemberInit(
                ((MemberInitExpression)mapB.Body).NewExpression,
                (new LambdaExpression[] { mapA, mapB }).SelectMany(e =>
                {
                    var bindings = ((MemberInitExpression)e.Body).Bindings.OfType<MemberAssignment>();
                    return bindings.Select(b =>
                    {
                        var paramReplacedExp = new ParameterReplaceVisitor(e.Parameters[0], param).VisitAndConvert(b.Expression, "Combine");
                        return Expression.Bind(b.Member, paramReplacedExp);
                    });
                })),
            param);
    }

    private class ParameterReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly ParameterExpression original;
        private readonly ParameterExpression updated;

        public ParameterReplaceVisitor(ParameterExpression original, ParameterExpression updated)
        {
            this.original = original;
            this.updated = updated;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node) => node == original ? updated : base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

The `Map` method of the extended class then becomes:

```cs
    public static Expression<Func<Data.Blog, BlogViewModel>> Map()
    {
        return BlogSummaryViewModel.Map().Concat(i => new BlogViewModel
        {
            PostCount = i.Posts.Count()
        });
    }
```